# Nested Scopes misunderstanding

Tags: python

I totally understand the idea of different scopes in Python but I can't understand this code clearly so I'd be pleased if someone can explain it to me, the return in line 18 what does it mean? shouldn't it be `return g()` for example? what does g means here is it a variable ? the output is z=function g at 0x15b43b0 , what does this mean?

one last thing , what does z() in the last line measn? there is no function called z !!

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x='abc'
        print 'x=',x
    def h():
        z=x
        print 'z=',z
    x=x+1
    print 'x=',x
    h()
    g()
    print 'x=',x
    return g

x=3
z=f(x)
print 'x=',x
print 'z=',z
z()
```

Comment: The function `f` returns the value of `g`, which is a function, so `f` returns a function. In the main code, that function is stored in `z`, so `z` really *is* a function, and can be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the return in line 18 what does it mean?

It's returning the function object `g` itself.

> shouldn't it be return g() for example?

Not necessarily.  It's perfectly acceptable to pass around functions as they're just objects like anything else in Python.  Both `return g` and `return g()` are valid, and mean different things.

> what does g means here is it a variable?

`g` is the name bound to a function object, which when called prints `x=abc` and then returns `None`.  Yes, `g` is a variable (it's a local variable).

> the output is z=function g at 0x15b43b0 , what does this mean?

It means the name `z` is bound to a function named `g` at memory location 0x15b43b0.  (Hint: It's actually the same function object that was bound to the name `g` in the inner scope)

> one last thing , what does z() in the last line measn?

It means call the object that the name `z` is bound to.  i.e. it calls the function that was returned by `f`.

> there is no function called z

There is no function with the `__name__` attribute equal to `z` here.  But the name `z` can still be bound to a function object.  Remember that objects can have more than one name (or no names at all).

Answer (score 1):

`g` is the name of a function defined with a `def`. `g()` invokes the function and gives you the result, while `g` is a name (a reference that is) for the function object itself.

Yes there is a funtion named 'z'. It is equal to the function returned by the invocation of `f(x)`, that is function f invoked with arg `x`. This is the function g as per the line with `return g`

Besides scopes you may want to check high-order functions and closure concepts.